# Flutter app error - getter 'value' was called on null

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm building one app where on top of Camera view I need to show something. Here is my code.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';

List<CameraDescription> cameras;

void main() async {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new CameraApp(),
  ));

}

class CameraApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CameraAppState createState() => new _CameraAppState();
}

class _CameraAppState extends State<CameraApp> {
  CameraController controller;
  var cameras;
  bool cameraGot = false;

  Future<Null> getCamera() async {
    cameras = await availableCameras();
    setState(() {
      this.cameras = cameras;
      this.cameraGot = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getCamera();
    super.initState();

    if(this.cameraGot) {
      controller = new CameraController(this.cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.medium);
      controller.initialize().then((_) {
        if (!mounted) {
          return;
        }
        setState(() {});
      });
    }

  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // camera widget
    Widget cameraView = new Container(
      child: new Row(children: [
          new Expanded(
            child: new Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio:
                        controller.value.aspectRatio,
                        child: new CameraPreview(controller)
                  )
                ]
            ),
          )
      ])
    );


    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          !this.controller.value.initialized ? new Container() : cameraView,

           // ---On top of Camera view add one mroe widget---

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Whenever I'm building the app I'm getting following error...

```
I/flutter ( 6911): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 6911): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building CameraApp(dirty, state: _CameraAppState#b6034):
I/flutter ( 6911): The getter 'value' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 6911): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 6911): Tried calling: value
```

Can't able to fig. out what's the error.

Comment: This helped me and now app works flawlessly, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58380075/flutter-shows-a-red-error-screen-before-loading-data-from-firebase-using-stream

Answer (score 23):

If you have created and assigned value to the variable and still it shows `getter 'value' was called on null`, 
try to `Run` or `Restart` your app instead of `Hot Reload`. Because `Hot Reload` will not call `initstate()` (where variables assign their values) which will be only called by `Restarting` the app.

Answer (score 8):

In the `initState`, you don't always instantiate a controller.

Which means it can be `null`. Therefore inside the `build` method, you need to check null to not crash

```
(!this.controller?.value?.initialized ?? false) ? new Container() : cameraView ,
```

Comment: I tried this but still, I'm getting the same error.

Comment: there's more then one place where you use controller. You need to check it everywhere

Comment: At this line also I've made changes like yours ```aspectRatio: (this.controller?.value?.aspectRatio) ?? false ``` but still no luck. Now, the error showing is ``` type 'bool' is not a subtype of type 'double' where```

Comment: Is controller?.value? are optionals like in swift ? @RémiRousselet

Answer (score 4):

```
aspectRatio: (this.controller?.value?.aspectRatio) ?? false
```

`aspectRatio` is a double value and you assigned it to `false` when it is `null`. Give it a double value.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem before and putting a height into the parent widget of `AspectRatio` fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

giving height to widget which is throwing error solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem this way:

```
children: <Widget>[
    (controller== null)
                      ? Container()
                      : controller.value.Initialized
                          ? Container(child: CameraPreview(controller))
                          : Container(),
    ],
```

Answer (score -2):

Most of the time. `HOT RESTART (R)` will fix this error.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer. Try to give some good example or explain it properly.

Comment: This will just restart the app, won't fix the error!

Comment: this removes error but again when you start app gives same error in my case

Comment: Worked when the problem surfaced during the Cupertino products app Flutter tutorial.